# PySpark making disjoint dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to using PySpark, and what I am trying to do is to split a dataframe with a single column(with the possibility of duplicate rows) into two dataframes such that 80% of the *distinct* rows end up in one dataframe and 20% end up in the other. Assume that the big dataframe is called `big_df` with the column `id`. The sequence of operations I'm doing to achieve this is as follows:

```
big_df = big_df.select('id').distinct() # Get all the distinct ids
bigger_chunk = big_df.sample(withReplacement=False, fraction=0.8) # Get approximately 80% 
smaller_chunk = big_df.join(bigger_chunk, 
                            [big_df.id == bigger_chunk.id],
                            how = 'left_outer')
```

So the idea here is to do a left join between big_df and a bigger_chunk and then select the rows in which `bigger_chunk.id IS NULL`. Since the join here leads to a dataframe with two columns with the same name, I do this:

```
cols = ['big_df_id', 'bigger_chunk_id']
smaller_chunk = smaller_chunk.toDF(*cols)
smaller_chunk = smaller_chunk.where(smaller_chunk.bigger_chunk_id.isNull()).
                                   select(smaller_chunk.big_df_id).toDF('id')
```

After this I have a sanity check to see if this actually worked:

```
print (bigger_chunk.count()+smaller_chunk.count() == big_df.count())
>>>> True
```

But when I do

```
bigger_chunk.select('id').intersect(smaller_chunk.select('id')).show()
```

I get a non-empty dataframe which doesn't make sense, because `bigger_chunk` and `smaller_chunk` should be disjoint, and this should result in an empty dataframe!

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong, or any insight into what's going on here would be really helpful!!!

Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that this is related to spark's lazy execution. When you call `.sample()`, it doesn't actually sample your dataframe - it just figures out how it *would* sample once an action has to be undertaken. So each time you interact with the dataframe, a different sample is being returned.

Comment: I think that seems to be the case... Everything works as expected when I do `bigger_chunk.cache()` and `bigger_chunk.count()`... Not sure if I have to do that everytime such a situation happens...